# How to draw incomplete components while subscribe is running?

Tags: angular, components, rxjs6

I have a "normal" subscription to get data from a http source, like this

```
sscmData.getRegistrations().subscribe(response => {
    this.registeredSkaters = response.map( item => item.skater )
})
```

The data are finally presented in a html table. Because the amount of data can be pretty huge it takes time until the table is shown.

Now I could show a "loading circle" or something else while creating the table, but I'm looking for a smarter solution.

Is it possible to show "incomplete loaded" tables or lists while data are still "loaded by subscribe()"? Is there any concept for doing this?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about network delay or rendering delay?

Comment: If you are talking about rendering delay, look into some "infinite scroll" implementation. Ideally you should never show ALL items if the number of DOM nodes go above critical levels. Use either pagination or infinite scroll.

Comment: rendering delay, only. I will give it a try. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the painting is "slow" you are probably blocking the ui thread. You should implement it at table level, most tables do have a pagination. If you want to delay the items, use delay and scan:

```
import { of, from, timer} from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, mergeMap, scan, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const arr = new Array(15)
  .fill(null)
  .map((_,i) => i);

const source = of(arr).pipe(
  mergeMap(x => from(x)),
  delay(50),
  scan((a: Array<number>,c: number) => [...a, c], [])
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

This will result in this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but I don't really think you can get incomplete data to display on the table. I can't even think as to how would that be possible.

That being said, the ideal way to go about this is to not get such bulks of data from the backend. Ideally, the responses are sent from a server in pages. So the actual response would have a field for current page number, current page size, and then records corresponding to that page number and page size.

If this Backend is something that you have control over, I'd recommend you to have it implemented in there.

That way it would have less load on your Frontend as well as your Backend, less data will be transferred over the network which would result in faster application load and better user experience.

Comment: well, I have the hope that there is any solution which makes it possible to draw and show a row when the data is available and which is not waiting until all rows of the table or list have been fully created...